# JS constructor class scope error

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

```
var bubbles;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400);
  bubbles = new Bubble();
}

function draw() {
  background(50);
  bubbles.displ();
  bubbles.mov();
}

class Bubble {

  constructor() {

    this.x = 200;
    this.y = 200;

  };

  displ() {
    noFill();
    stroke(255);
    strokeWeight(4);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, 25, 25);
  };

  mov() {
    this.x = this.x + random(-1, 1);
    this.y = this.y + random(-1, 1);
  }
}
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

14: *Uncaught SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode*

Did you just try to use p5.js's str() function?

If so, you may want to move it into your sketch's setup() function. For more details, see [here](http://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#why-cant-i-assign-variables-using-p5-functions-and-variables-before-setup).

What is wrong here?

Comment: This error doesn't happen went I tested the code. Where are you running this ?

Comment: i use sketch.js

Comment: Where you have written `"use strict";` ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all... You are not allowed to declare variables before setup.

And there is a solution for your problem, too. [1](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode) I have rewritten it so it fits your code.

```
var s = function( sketch ) {

    var bubbles;

    function setup() {
      sketch.createCanvas(600,400);
      bubbles = new Bubble();
    }

    function draw() {
      sketch.background(50);
      sketch.bubbles.displ();
      sketch.bubbles.mov();
    }
};

var myp5 = new p5(s);
```

---

[1](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode) From the github repository referred to in your error-message: https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode